# search multiple criteria if then else on Access 2010 unbound form using VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access-2010

I have the following simple and easy code:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
Dim db As Database, rsAtype As Recordset, Criteria As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsAtype = db.OpenRecordset("Asset_Types", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

Criteria = "Type='" & NOA & "'"

rsAtype.FindFirst Criteria

'****  Following code is Adding a new type of asset to the Asset_Types Table****
If rsAtype.NoMatch Then

        rsAtype.AddNew
        rsAtype("Type") = Me!NOA
        rsAtype("Description") = Me!Desc
        rsAtype.Update
MsgBox "New Asset Added"
    rsAtype.Close
    db.Close
    DoCmd.Close
Else
        MsgBox "Asset Type " & Me!NOA & " already exists.", 48, "ERROR!"
        Me!NOA.SetFocus

End If

End Sub
```

Here I am searching if asset type already exists then give warning instead of updating, is there any way I could search multiple columns in a table using just one If statement, I don't want to create nested If statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply combine the multiple criteria. For example:

```
strCriteria = "[PlantID]=" & Me!PlantID & " AND [Location]= '" & Me!Location & "'"
```

Here, the first parameter `PlantID` is intended to be an integer and the second, `Location`, a string (hence the single quotes).

Comment: Hi Mitch, I got a type mismatch error in the following code:

    Criteria = "Supplier_name='" & Me!Supnamebox & "'" And "Contact_name='" & Me!ContPerbox & "'" And "Contact_number='" & Me!Me!Phonebox & "'" And "Contact_email='" & Me!emailbox & "'"

Comment: All the fields mentioned above are Text.

Comment: Try using double quotes (as in quoted double (x2)) instead of single? It's been a while since I wrote any ADO code.

Comment: Hey Mitch, they already are double quotes:
`Criteria = "Supplier_name='" & Me!Supnamebox & "'" And "Contact_name='" & Me!ContPerbox & "'" And "Contact_number='" & Me!Me!Phonebox & "'" And "Contact_email='" & Me!emailbox & "'" `

Comment: SOrry I understand what you mean when you say double X2, I tried that but got a "Compile error: Expected end of statement."

Comment: Mitch the only thing that was missing in your code was a single quote, but you still answered my question, I needed to know how to add multiple things in one criteria which you helped me with. Thanks mate.

Comment: To be fair, nothing was missing in my example code. The first param is intended to be an int (ID) and the second a string (hence the single quotes), but I probably should make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer, the AND had to be part of the quotes:

## OLD CODE

```
Criteria = "Supplier_name='" & Me!Supnamebox & "'" And "Contact_name='" & Me!ContPerbox & "'" And "Contact_number='" & Me!Me!Phonebox & "'" And "Contact_email='" & Me!emailbox & "'"
```

## NEW CODE

```
Criteria = "Supplier_name='" & Me!Supnamebox & "' AND Contact_name='" & Me!ContPerbox & "' AND Contact_number='" & Me!Phonebox & "' AND Contact_email='" & Me!emailbox & "'"
```

i have tested it and it works, word of advise though, the syntax is right but the logic I was using is wrong, I should be using OR instead of AND. OR is testing if there is any field that matches, AND will only give an error if all the fields match, otherwise it lets you add a duplicate record.